# Grafana variable for all prometheus metrics with prefix

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I would like a [Grafana variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/) that contains all the Prometheus metric names with a given prefix. I would like to do this so I can control what graphs are displayed with a drop down menu. I'd like to be able to display all the metrics matching the prefix without having to create a query for each one. In the Grafana documentation under the Prometheus data source I see:

> metrics(metric)   Returns a list of metrics matching the specified metric regex.

-- [Using Prometheus in Grafana](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/)

I tried creating a variable in Grafana using this `metrics` function but it didn't work. See the screenshot for the variable settings I have:

settings[image]

As you can see the "Preview of values" only shows "None"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In promql, you can select metrics by name by using the internal `__name__` label:

```
{__name__=~"mysql_.*"}
```

And then, you can reuse it to extract the metrics name using [query](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/prometheus/#query-variable) `label_values()`:

```
label_values({__name__=~"mysql_.*"},__name__)
```

This will populate your variable with metrics name starting with `mysql_`.

You can get the same result using `metrics()`; I don't know why it doesn't work for you (it should also works with prefix):

```
metrics(mysql_)
```

Comment: It looks like my syntax was wrong. I was doing `metrics(/mysql_*/)` because I thought it required regex, but `metrics(mysql_)` actually does what I want. Thanks!